# Backspace in shell moves cursor to the right

Tags: ssh, terminal, tty, kubernetes

There's this remote shell I login into that, when I try to delete a character, instead of visually showing the character being deleted, it remains there and the cursor moves to the right. This shell is running Bash.

For example, if I type `echoo` and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> once, the prompt will look like this: `echoo` . However, in reality the characters that are present will be correct (`echo`) and if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the command runs fine.

As far as I can tell, it's exactly same issue that was opened [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2346). I, too, am connecting through Kubernetes. The command I run looks something like `kubectl -n <some_kind_of_argument> exec -it <another_argument> -- bash`.

From reading other question, I get that the following is useful information.

---

```
root# echo $TERM
xterm
```

This isn't the same value that is output by my local shell (`xterm-256color`). The following does not fix the issue.

```
root# export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Now I share the output of `stty -a`.

```
root# stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 43; columns 118; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Now, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> followed by pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> displays this:

```
root# ^?
```

This seems aligned with the output above (`erase = ^?`). Pressing enter on the above prompt prints. . .

```
bash: $'\177': command not found
```

I also ran `stty sane`, but that didn't help.

---

Can someone help me fix this and hopefully also help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The remote shell/application that you're using expects backspace to send `^H` (which would usually move the cursor left one cell in a **terminal**).  The shell/application prints a space to erase the character.  But it does not expect `^?` (ASCII DEL, code 127), which generally does not move the cursor in a **terminal**.

> However, in reality the characters that are present will be correct (echo) and if I hit Enter the command runs fine.

The comment in the question does say that the shell/application actually treats `^?` as an erase-character, but in some sense it may be hard-coded.  But if it is not hard-coded, it may pay attention to the `stty` setting.  If it does, you could do this in your (remote) shell initialization

```
stty erase ^H
```

(a real control/`H`...) and then use <kbd>*Control*</kbd><kbd>`H`</kbd>, instead of <kbd>*Backspace*</kbd> (or change your terminal configuration to send `^H` rather than `^?`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have enough reputation to up vote. "Whether the shell/application actually treats `^?` as an erase-character isn't clear from the question." Is there anything I can do to provide information regarding this? I'm happy to do it.

Comment: "If it refuses to cooperate, you can give in, using <kbd>*Control*</kbd><kbd>`H`</kbd> instead of <kbd>*Backspace*</kbd> (or change your terminal configuration to send `^H` rather than `^?`)." How do I go about doing this? I'd prefer a solution that was somewhat more permanent (like a configuration or passing some option to `bash`), but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: "isn't clear" was just that I lost focus on the point to be made in the question.

Comment: Thank you for adding more details. Alas, it didn't work for me. Now, when I send `Ctrl+H`, the cursor moves to the right.